# MVC Code First Entity Framework SaveChanges Fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
// POST: Categories/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,CategoryName,ParentCategory,Description")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Categories.Add(category);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(category);
        }
```

The above is my Categories create action. I am getting an exception on the save changes method. It started once I made my ID field for the category classes an identity field and I don't want my users to have to put in their own ID field, as that should be auto generated. Here is the code for my ID property.

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
```

Now it was working when I had to enter in my own ID on the form and now when I try to run the add to the database context and save. I come accross this exception message..

> An exception of type >'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in >EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an >unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted >since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 >for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency >exceptions.

It is just me working on the project so nobody else is updating my local db while trying to insert. I followed the link and it seems like there isn't a straight forward way to have this run without doing a try catch. What am I missing? What is the most effective way to do what I trying to do?

UPDATE: I tried making a migration and updating the database and I also have tried removing the ID from the include and it doesn't work. Here is the code in the up method in the migration.

```
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Product", "Category_ID1", "dbo.Category");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Category");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Category", "ID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Category", "ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Product", "Category_ID1", "dbo.Category", "ID");
```

UPDATE

This is the code in my Category class.

```
namespace SeniorProjectMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    [Table("Category")]
    public partial class Category
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Category()
        {
            Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        [Key]               
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength]
        public string CategoryURL { get; set; }

        public int? ParentCategory { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should remove "Id" from Bind Include in your Create method

Comment: I gave that a shot and it still didn't work. Should I add a migration and update db?

Comment: If you changed your field to Identity and did not updated your database, it sure is a problem.. you probably have a `ID = 0` in your database.

Comment: I updated the question and Ill update the question with it. However that did not save my problem..

Comment: After your `db.Categories.Add(category);`, does your DataContext have changes (`dbset.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)`)?

Comment: if(db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added) )
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }                                        
If I add this around my save changes, it still gets hit and I still get the same exception.
@GabrielGM

Comment: Can you post your `Category` model and the debugging values of the category you're trying to create?